# Are there any WCF Configuration Tools out there that will make the job easier

Tags: wcf-configuration

Are there any tools that go beyond requiring deep and intimate knowledge of every configuration option and nuance and will just setup an application with a minimum of inputs. Something like a wizard that produces the XML configuration based on those simple inputs. I don't care about security I just need the service to work. Ideally the tool would be able to setup IIS6 as well or at least with a given set of options it would produce a list of steps I needed to complete in IIS.

The Microsoft Service Configuration Editor is no better than direct editing of the XMl. I did find a web site that has the right idea but it wasn't able to solve my simple installation. (http://www.noemax.com/support/wcf_binding_configuration_wizard.html).

Is there anything out there that puts some convention into play over this mountain of configuration?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

WCF configuration can look very daunting at first, indeed! I like that configuration wizard you linked to - why wasn't it good enough for you?

I don't know of any tool right now, that would solve your problem and help you figure out the proper configuration - it really boils down to learning the ropes and getting to know the ins and outs of it, I'm afraid.

Basically, what I've learned is : don't even start to imagine all the things you *could* do - try to focus on what you *should* do (and what you need).

Really, it boils down to about five scenarios as outlined in the excellent book "[Programming WCF](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596521308)" by Juval Lowy:

- intranet apps (use the NetTcp binding, Windows security)
- internet apps (use the wsHttp binding if ever possible, username/pwd or certificates for security)
- business-to-business apps (use whatever binding makes sense, secure by certificates)
- queue message delivery (MSMQ)
- no-security apps (legacy ASMX support, interop with "dumb" webservice clients)

Basically, pick the one you need, and from there, you're pretty much set as to what to do and how to do it. I would definitely recommend checking out Juval's book - excellent excellent resource!

So the question is: which category does your app fit in? Based on that, you can pretty much determine all that's needed from there.

Also, I watched two screencasts that really helped me get over the heaps of configuration options in WCF, and focus on what's really important:

- [Extreme WCF](http://www.dnrtv.com/default.aspx?showNum=122) with Miguel Castro
- [Demystifying WCF](http://www.dnrtv.com/default.aspx?showNum=135) with Keith Elder

Both gave me a good feel for what configuration is *really* needed - and what is just fluff.

Hope that helps some!

Marc

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Watched the first video and did some refactoring. My project is now running. This is a much simpler approach wish I knew about before wasting so much time. I still think there needs to be additional tools like wizards that help with the deployment and operations end of things. I rather spend my time developing than troubleshooting deployment and operational environments.

Comment: Glad I could help! Yes, of course - such a tool would be helpful. Why don't you write it and make it available to the community? :-)